# Why attribute a didn't show in page 2 and so on datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

I has make datatable with laravel in simple mode like this

```
<tbody>
  @php
    $i = 1;
  @endphp
  @foreach ($data_transaction as $item)
  @php
    $encrypt = Crypt::encrypt($item->id);
  @endphp
  <tr>
    <td>{{$i}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->work_order_number}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->customer_name}}</td>
    <td>Rp {{number_format($item->details->sum('amount'))}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="{{url('read-transaction-' . $encrypt)}}"><i data-feather="eye"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @php
    $i++;
  @endphp
  @endforeach
```

in page one, everything looks ok.

[image]

But afther that, in page 2 and so on the view icon is disappear

[image]

my datatables initialization just like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datatables').DataTable();
  feather.replace()
})
```

Am I did something wrong?

Comment: What is this line: feather.replace()?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datatables').DataTable({
    deferRender: true
  });
  feather. Replace();
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I added the callback function in datatable and the issue was resolved. Kindly check the below Answer.

```html
$('.datatables').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        feather.replace();
    }
} );
```

Hope this will help you.